# How can I set cookies in my Electron JS application using response headers from my backend like in Postman?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, electron

Setting cookies from response-header in electron js

Hi there, I'm new in developing application using electron JS. Now I'm currently working on the authentication components. The problem is when I try my backend on Postman the cookies got set, but when I try to authenticate from electronJS application to backend I got the set-cookie on response-headers but cookie didn't get set in electron app. I have attached the image for postman response, electron application response and application -> cookies in electron app. I'm using this video `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4AhvYORZRY&t=11035s`  as a reference for the MERN authentication system.

[Postman response with cookies set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WQ3g.png)

[Receive a response on electron app with set-cookie header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNjxf.png)

[Screenshot from application->cookies in electron app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlTvT.png)

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed those after almost 2 days. I tried to build the application to try if the cookies work or not for the first time, unfortunately it doesn't work. But after I changed a few things on the frontend and the backend the build works but not in development just in production. Here's how I fixed it:

Frontend:
I used this code to run the file not the URL in production mode

```
const appURL = app.isPackaged ? url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, "index.html"),
    protocol: "file:",
    slashes: true,
  }) : 
  "http://localhost:3376";
  mainWindow.loadURL(appURL);
```

Backend:
Here I changed the `sameSite: 'none'` and `secure: 'secure'`.
The generateToken code originally is from [here](https://github.com/bradtraversy/mern-auth/blob/master/backend/utils/generateToken.js).